# What is the diameter of the nozzle of Trent 1000?

Tags: airliner, jet-engine

I am researching how much force is needed to divert the thrust of a Boeing 787 on its service ceiling of 13,100 meters and at a cruising speed of 913 km/h (data found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_787_Dreamliner)).

As I would like to fit a diverter to it, what is the diameter of the nozzle of [Trent 1000 engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_Trent_1000)?

Comment: What is the purpose of the exercise? There are no obvious reasons why anyone would want to divert thrust of an airliner at cruise - most airliners have a rather narrow flight envelope at full cruise, diverting thrust would likely produce a stall.

Comment: "I would like to fit a diverter to it" - **do not** perform such a major modification to a plane without a license and without checking with the aircraft manufacturer first.

Answer (score 2):

It is mentioned here that the fan diameter is about 111-112 inches. So the nozzle must be smaller than that as the engine assembly narrows at its rear end.

This [PDF (p.5)](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/apl/research/aircraft_technology/cleen/2012_consortium/media/Boeing_CLEEN_Projects_Briefing.pdf) shows a diagram of the exhaust nozzle of RR Trent 1000 measuring the diameter as **63** inches. This is the only reference I could find.